# Replacing width and height properties with proper viewBox values

Tags: javascript, html, svg

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683135/understanding-svgs-viewbox-attribute) is helpful in understanding the purpose of viewBox, but isn't quite the same.

The goal is to replace the width and height properties of an SVG element with a corresponding viewBox property. Our code requires viewBox to be set, and not width and height.

Is there an algorithmic way of doing this?

For instance, the SVG element below when replaced with a viewBox property of 0 0 6 6 does not look the same.

**Original**

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='6' height='6'>
<rect width='6' height='6' fill='#eee'/>
<g id='c'>
<rect width='3' height='3' fill='#e6e6e6'/>
<rect y='1' width='3' height='2' fill='#d8d8d8'/>
</g>
<use xlink:href='#c' x='3' y='3'/>
</svg>
```

**Edited**

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox="0 0 6 6">
<rect width='6' height='6' fill='#eee'/>
<g id='c'>
<rect width='3' height='3' fill='#e6e6e6'/>
<rect y='1' width='3' height='2' fill='#d8d8d8'/>
</g>
<use xlink:href='#c' x='3' y='3'/>
</svg>
```

**Sandbox**
https://jsbin.com/micepar/embed?html,output

Comment: what's wrong with you ? svg width and height are for html size, viewbox values are for position and scale of the svg part

Comment: "The goal is to replace the width and height properties of an SVG element with a corresponding viewBox property." Why? They are completely different things with completely different effects.

Comment: @Crashalot Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583873/7394871 may be useful where in detail with examples the tasks that perform the `width` and` height` and `viewBox` for scaling and positioning are explained

Comment: Without a width and height it is up to the application to interpret how to display. Which means since it is your application only you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: You can't, that's not what `viewBox` does.

An SVG canvas can be considered to be an infinite drawing surface. `viewBox` tells the browser which part should be visible. This visible area will be scaled and positioned to fit the element's content area. The defaults for `viewBox` are usually such that x and y are 0 while width and height match the element's pixel dimensions. However, `viewBox` does not change those dimensions.

An SVG element's height and width change the element's content area. The `viewBox` area is scaled to fit this content area. If height and width are not set, they will be some convenient size depending on browser implementation and are not dependent on `viewBox` even if they appear to be in certain situations.